# Microsoft.Practices Transient Fault Handling in .NET 4.5.x

Tags: c#, azure

We've recently upgraded our source code to .NET 4.5 and have come across a problem with Transient Fault handling.  As part of the upgrade we changed the Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.Core.dll file version from 5.0.1118.0 to 5.1.1209.1 (which may or may not be related).  We create our own instantantiation of IsTransient and now we get the following error when running the application:

> Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member:
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus.ServiceBusTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.IsTransient(System.Exception)'.
>   Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the
>   security accessibility of the method being overriden.

So far I've tried the following without success:

1. Copying the DLL to the GAC
2. Added `[SecurityCritical]` at method and assembly level and also tried different Security headers.
3. Added `[assembly: System.Security.SecurityRules(System.Security.SecurityRuleSet.Level2, SkipVerificationInFullTrust = true)]`in AssemblyInfo.cs and as a header for the class.  I also tried this for Level1 and tried removing the SkipVerification.

So now I am officially stuck.  As I understand it the issue is because of the new security rules in .NET 4 but none of the fixes I've tried so far have worked.  Has anyone come across this specific issue in this specific DLL before (or similar)?